# Existe um modo de criar uma execução paralela usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Queria saber se existe um modo de usar paralelismo em `javascript`.
Pra quem vem do mundo do `java` ou do `C` esse é um termo bastante conhecido e utilizado, as conhecidas `threads`.

> Paralelismo => é um programa com capacidade de dividir tarefas em
>   pequenas partes e executá-las em paralelo.

Fiquei pensando em um processo que ficasse rodando em `standy-by` assim como pode ser feito na programação de mais baixo nível com `while(1)` por exemplo, que fica aguardando a iteração de algum processo externo, consumindo algum `web-service`, enquanto que esse processamento não travasse a minha aplicação `front-end`.

Não sei se com uma imagem eu consigo deixar isso mais claro...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo o seguinte código:

```
<imput id="a" type="text">
<script>
  (function() {
    x = a.value;
    while (1) {
      if (x === "string") {
        alert("entrou");
      }
    }
  )

  function teste() {
    alert("Sou uma função");
  }
</script>
```

Se rodado trava qualquer navegador, na verdade trava somente a pagina em que foi executado por causa do `while(1)`.... na minha visão, se fosse possível montar isso em processos paralelos, não travaria.

Comment: @bfavaretto deu uma resposta acerca desse assunto [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-ass%c3%adncrona-funciona-em-javascript/16960#16960). Já é um tanto esclarecedor =]

Comment: Então @LucasCosta, acerda da resposta do bfavaretto, a minha pergunta  é mais pra saber se existe um modo de criar threads de processos paralelos :)  é um pouquinho diferente o conceito de assíncrono com thread

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, é possível utilizando Web Workers.

O código a ser executado em uma Thread separada devera estár em um arquivo separado, ele recebera o conteúdo da thread principal através do evento `onmessage` e irá enviar pelo método `postMessage`.

Na Thread Principal você deverá criar um Worker, este terá um evento `onmessage` para receber as mensagens e poderá enviar usando o método `postMessage`.

Abaixo segue um exemplo completo, para criar uma URL para o Worker, estou montando o script em memoria.

```js
var generateUrl = function (id) {
  var dom = document.getElementById(id);
  var blob = new Blob([dom.textContent], { type: dom.type });
  return URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

var workerUrl = generateUrl("worker");
var worker = new Worker(workerUrl);
worker.onmessage = function (event) {
  alert(event.data);
}
worker.postMessage('Hello World!');
```

```html
<script id="worker" type="text/task">
  onmessage = function (event) {  
    var reverse = event.data.split("").reverse().join("");
    postMessage(reverse);
  } 
</script>
```

A algum tempo atrás tentei realizar uma implementação com Workers e me surgiu uma duvida, a resposta dada pelo @Gomiero pode lhe ajudar a entender alguns fatores.:
[C# Parallel.ForEach equivalente em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109195/c-parallel-foreach-equivalente-em-javascript)

Por fim, se precisa manter uma comunicação client-servidor para receber atualizações de novos registros, WebWorker não é o caminho.

Até mesmo o seguinte script pode lhe ser uma melhor opção.:

```
var atualizarConteudo = function (response) {

}

var atualizar = function () {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
  httpRequest.addEventListener("onreadystatechange", function (event) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
        atualizarConteudo(httpRequest.response);
      }
      //adicionar um delay entre as requisições.
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        atualizar();
      }, 1000);          
    }
  })
  httpRequest.send();
}
```

Seguindo esta linha de raciocínio, a sua melhor opção seria utilizar um `WebSocket`, como não sei o que está a utilizar no servidor, vou lhe dá algumas opções.:

- ASP.NET: [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)
- NodeJS: [SocketIO](http://socket.io)
- PHP: [Ratchet](http://socketo.me)