# Usar múltiplos loops javascript

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de rodar mais de um setInterval() ao mesmo tempo? 
Nesse meu código, se eu rodar duas vezes a função "interval" o programa entra em loop infinito e no console fica tenho: 
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8......] infinitamente

```js
arraya = []
arrayb = []
function interval(array, length, count) {
    a = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        array.push(count);
        if (array.length > length) {
            console.log(array.join(' '));
            clearInterval(a);
        }
    }, 150);;
}
interval(arraya, 4, 0);
// interval(arrayb, 9, 0)
```

Comment: Me pareceu uma duvida meio similar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178944/existe-um-modo-de-criar-uma-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-paralela-usando-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema no seu código é que `a` é uma variável global.Se você trocar por uma variável local tudo funciona direitinho.

```js
arraya = []
arrayb = []
function interval(array, length, count) {
    var a = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        array.push(count);
        if (array.length > length) {
            console.log(array.join(' '));
            clearInterval(a);
        }
    }, 150);;
}
interval(arraya, 4, 0);
interval(arrayb, 9, 0)
```

Comment: Funcionou :) muito obrigado pela ajuda! Vou testar em outros programas depois.

Comment: @anotherbeginner10 olá e bem vindo. Acho importante veres isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta

Answer (score 1):

o problema era que o a estava sendo jogado no contexto global, logo na segunda execução o identificador do primeiro setInterval era perdido e apenas o segundo parava, basta adicionar `var` antes de `a` para resolver isso

```js
arraya = []
arrayb = []
function interval(array, length, count) {
    var a = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        array.push(count);
        if (array.length > length) {
            console.log(array.join(' '));
            clearInterval(a);
        }
    }, 150);;
}
interval(arraya, 4, 0);
interval(arrayb, 9, 0)
```