# Como funciona o pool de threads do node

Tags: javascript, node.js, thread, threadpool

Partindo do princípio que o JavaScript, tanto no browser como no node, é single thread (me corrijam se estiver errado), como funciona o pool de thread?

Se, por enquanto, meu servidor não recebe muitas requisições ou está em desenvolvimento (só recebe as minhas requisições de teste), faz sentido diminuir o `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`?

Se meu servidor está recebendo muitas requisições há algum ganho aumentar o `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`?

No caso de um servidor que possui pequenos e grandes processos

Comment: Existe uma inverdade nessa pergunta, existe sim a possibilidade de se criar múltiplas "threads" em js. veja: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178944/existe-um-modo-de-criar-uma-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-paralela-usando-javascript),[2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178944/existe-um-modo-de-criar-uma-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-paralela-usando-javascript)

Comment: Funciona idêntico a qualquer outro esquema de pool de recursos. Semelhante ao `RunnerPool` (ou qualquer nome semelhante) do Java

Comment: @MarceloBoni impressão minha ou os dois links são iguais?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado, sabe me dizer sobre o uso do `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam http://docs.libuv.org/en/latest/threadpool.html ; estudando para dar uma resposta mais assertiva

Comment: Errei na hora de colar o segundo link [2*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100654/como-liberar-thread-congelado-travado)

Comment: @MarceloBoni me parece errado dizer que é possível ciar múltiplas threads no javascript, apesar de poder rodar uma parte da aplicação isoladamente, não seria uma outra thread, pensando assim, poderia abrir dois terminais e executar dois arquivos `.js`, no node, por exemplo, e dizer que o javascript é multi thread

Comment: Por isso a enfase em **threads** no meu comentário, não é exatamente o mesmo método, porém emula bem o comportamento, dependendo do que desejar fazer, acredito que a principal diferença é que em outros tipos de linguagens você quebra a tarefa em mini-tarefas, no js você não quebra a tarefa, mas você cria outras tarefas que executam simultaneamente. Leia mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39961/3956218).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### NodeJs Thread pool

Sim no NodeJs o seu código executa apenas numa única thread, contudo isso não restringe o Node de criar novas threads para determinadas operações, caso seja necessário.

O conceito que você tem que entender é que o NodeJS processa uma lista de eventos, isto é conhecido como *event loop*. Uma forma simples de entender o *event loop* é por exemplo num servidor `HTTP`. Quando um pedido `HTTP` chegar ao seu servidor Node é inserido um novo item para processar na lista de eventos. E em determinado ponto o Node chamará o código que você tem registado para tratar esse evento.

Operações demoradas podem e devem fazer uso do loop de eventos do Node. O objectivo é que se uma operação for muito demorada, o *event loop* do Node possa continuar em execução enquanto essa operação é processada.

Quando a operação completar ela registará um evento no *event loop* e mais uma vez o seu código executará na mesma thread de sempre.

### UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE

Regra geral em questões sobre a configuração de determinados valores padrão especificados pela plataforma é que você não os deve mudar.

Antes de mudar algum desses valores com o intuito de optimizar o desempenho você deverá ser rigoroso nos seus testes e usar um profiler para verificar se obtém algum beneficio.

[SOEN - When is the thread pool used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644328/when-is-the-thread-pool-used)